# Fetching data in componentDidMount occurs in warning "Can only update a mounted or mounting component"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, fetch

I fetch data in React Native with `fetch(url, ...)` in my `componentDidMount()` method.

So my class looks something like

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://...').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      this.setState({ posts: res.posts });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <FlatList data={this.state.posts} ... />;
  }
}
```

It worked fine all until I started using `redux` and `redux-persist`.

Now I get the warning `Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. ...`.

I don't understand why this is happening since it should be mounted if it's called in `componentDidMount`.

I am wondering if I need to abort fetching in `componentWillUnmount` or if I should actually fetch the data to the redux store instead of only storing the data temporarily in the 'local component'. When I open most other apps, it seems the data is already loaded when I open the app - is this due to very fast data retrieval or are they saving the data in a persisting store?

I have seen some projects where they use `if (this.isMounted) { .. }` inside `componentDidMount`, but as I understand the lifecycle of this method, the component would always have been mounted at this time. Also, it seems `isMounted` is deprecated.

What am I doing wrong? The issue only occurs when I start the app, so there's no problem if I navigate to another route and then back to this route.

Answer (score 3):

Since `fetch` is async, the component might not be mounted when the data arrives. when the arrow functions inside your `then`s are being called, the component had already finished mounting and continued to rendering probably. This the nature of `Promise`.

You should make sure the component is still mounted when setting it's state, like this:

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    fetch('https://...').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      if(this.mounted) this.setState({ posts: res.posts });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    return <FlatList data={this.state.posts} ... />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But the approach seems a bit strange to me. Would it make sense to fetch the data with redux instead?

Comment: When I'm working with redux I do that, but it doesn't always make sense. Yes, redux will free you of worrying about mounting (because of `connect`) but then again, now you need to clear that data from memory when unmounting possibly (depending on whether you want to cache it or not).

There are other ways to fetch this data with less of a mess and not committing to keeping it in a global state (which doesn't always fit). My favorite would be `recompose`.

Comment: Food for thought on why this isn't the best approach: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html